# Why isn't all the data showing up in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-9

Want to ask why my data from the database (MySQL) doesn't all appear on the website from the `grades` table join with the `grade_details` table, my database is attached:

[Screenshot my Database in MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN1Ax.png)

So this data is from the join `grades` table with join `grade_details` taken from the `id_grade` data like the table above.

[Screenshot in web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOlau.png)

As given by the blue contact in the Quiz table, only ***Student31*** values appear, while the other Quiz values are at ***0***, but the student names ***Servira*** and ***Student4*** already have values, namely ***90*** and ***80***, as in the `grade_details` table in the database. But to avoid confusion, the Servira and Student4 data don't show up with a value of only 0. Even though I have used a join with another table, the other quiz scores cannot be read, only 1 student readable value data.

***Code:***

**Model Grade Detail:**

```
class GradeDetail extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_grade_detail';
    protected $table = 'grade_details';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id_grade_detail',
        'id_grade',
        'id_student',
        'quiz',
        'assignment',
        'd_t',
        'min_text',
        'final_text',
        'total',
    ];

    public function grades(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Grade::class, 'id_grade','id_grade');
    }

    public function students(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id_student','id');
    }
}
```

**Mode Grade:**

```
class Grade extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_grade';
    protected $table = 'grades';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id_grade',
        'id_subject',
        'id_academic_year',
        'id_semester',
        'min_score',
        'done',
    ];

    public function details(){
        return $this->belongsTo(GradeDetail::class, 'id_grade','id_grade');
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function ViewGrade($id){
    $subject = Grade::join('subjects', 'grades.id_subject', '=', 'subjects.id_sub')
        ->join('class_infos', 'subjects.id_class', '=', 'class_infos.id')
        ->join('class_details', 'class_infos.id', '=', 'class_details.id_class')
        ->join('users', 'class_details.id_user', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('subjects.id_teacher', '=', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('grades.id_grade', '=', $id)
        ->get();

    return view('teacher.grade.view_grade', compact('subject'));
}
```

**Blade:**

```
<table class="w-full text-sm text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
    <thead class="text-xs text-white uppercase bg-[#464867] dark:bg-[#464867]">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="py-3 px-6">
            No
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="py-3 px-6">
            NISN
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="py-3 px-6">
            Name Student
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="py-3 px-6">
            Min Score
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="py-3 px-6">
            Quiz
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="py-3 px-6">
            Assignment
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="py-3 px-6">
            Daily Tests
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="py-3 px-6">
            Min Exam
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="py-3 px-6">
            Final Exam
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="py-3 px-6">
            Total
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @php $no = 1; @endphp
    @forelse($subject as $data)
        <tr class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700">
            <th scope="row" class="py-4 px-6 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                {{$no++}}
            </th>
            <th scope="row" class="py-4 px-6 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                {{$data->username}}
            </th>
            <th scope="row" class="py-4 px-6 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                {{$data->name}}
            </th>
            <th scope="row" class="py-4 px-6 font-medium text-red-700 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                {{$data->min_score}}
            </th>
            <th scope="row" class="py-4 px-6 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                @if(!empty($data->details))
                    {{ (!empty( $data->id == $data->details->id_student )) ? $data->details->quiz: 0}}
                @else
                    0
                @endif
            </th>
            <th scope="row" class="py-4 px-6 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                @if(!empty($data->details))
                    {{$data->details->assignment}}
                @else
                    0
                @endif
            </th>
            <th scope="row" class="py-4 px-6 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                @if(!empty($data->details))
                    {{$data->details->d_t}}
                @else
                    0
                @endif
            </th>
            <th scope="row" class="py-4 px-6 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                @if(!empty($data->details))
                    {{$data->details->min_text}}
                @else
                    0
                @endif
            </th>
            <th scope="row" class="py-4 px-6 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                @if(!empty($data->details))
                    {{$data->details->final_text}}
                @else
                    0
                @endif
            </th>
            <th scope="row" class="py-4 px-6 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                @if(!empty($data->details))
                    {{$data->details->total}}
                @else
                    0
                @endif
            </th>
        </tr>
    @empty
        <tr colspan = "10" class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700">
            <td class="py-4 px-6 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                No Data
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforelse

    </tbody>
</table>
```

How do you make the **Servira** and **Student4** column name fields filled with grades on quizzes on the web as well as in the `grade_details` database table?

Answer (score 1):

in your model Grade you should specify the **details** relationship as a **HasMany** relation not a **BelongsTo** relation so your model would be :

```
public function details(){
    $this->hasMany(GradeDetail::class, 'id_grade','id_grade');  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@AlirezaSalehi is correct. It is indeed a `hasMany` relationship. The correct `details` relationship in your `Grade` is indeed:

```
public function details(){
    $this->hasMany(GradeDetail::class, 'id_grade','id_grade');  
}
```

In the `GradeDetail` model, your primary key is `id_grade_detail` (not `id`), which is fine, so your relationships should be as following:

```
public function grades(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Grade::class, 'id_grade','id_grade_detail');
}

public function students(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id_student','id_grade_detail');
}
```

Where `id_student` is the **primary key** of the `User` model, which I assume by the code you have given (out of the box, the primary key of the `User` model is `id`, did you change that?)

Check the documentation at https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

In my experience, it's good practice to follow the Laravel conventions, explained on the same page. Unless you have no other choice, f.ex. if the DB is already in existence. If it's a fresh project, consider to follow the conventions. It will safe you debugging time later on. *(speaking of personal experience)*